# Can 2 classes share a friend function?

Tags: c++, friend-function

Today i have a doubt regarding friend function.
Can two classes have same friend function?
Say example 
`friend void f1();` 
declared in class A and class B. Is this possible? If so, can a function f1() can access the members of two classes?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Yes, `f1()` would have access to members of both classes.

Comment: Have you tried compiling a simple example? This seems like it would be easy to test.

Comment: What makes you think this would _not_ be possible?

Answer (score 18):

An example will explain this best:

```
class B;                   //defined later

void add(A,B);

class A{
    private:
    int a;
    public:
    A(){ 
        a = 100;
    }
    friend void add(A,B);
};   

class B{
    private:
    int b;
    public:
    B(){ 
        b = 100;
    }
    friend void add(A,B);
};

void add (A Aobj, B Bobj){
    cout << (Aobj.a + Bobj.b);
}

main(){
    A A1;
    B B1;
    add(A1,B1);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much man ur example was very nice and easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction on what function can or cannot be `friends`'s of `class`'s, so yes there's no problem with this.

Comment: Well, you have to be able to name the function, but that's a natural restriction. E.g. `struct { static void foo(); };` or functions in anonymous namespaces in other translation units.

Answer (score 1):

correction to the above code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class B;                   //defined later
class A;                  //correction (A also need be specified)
void add(A,B);

class A{
    private:
    int a;
    public:
    A(){
        a = 100;
    }
    friend void add(A,B);
};

class B{
    private:
    int b;
    public:
    B(){
        b = 100;
    }
    friend void add(A,B);
};

void add (A Aobj, B Bobj){
    cout << (Aobj.a + Bobj.b);
}

main(){
    A A1;
    B B1;
    add(A1,B1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class first
{
    friend void getdata(first object1, int i);
};

class second
{
    friend void getdata(second object2, int j);
};

getdata(first object1, int i, second object2, int j)
{
    cout<<i+j;
}

main()
{
    first object1;
    second object2;
    getdata(object1, 5, object2, 7);
}
```

Comment: friends functions are intended to have access to classes private members