# Illegal reference to non-static member in 2 classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have problem with my class/pointers.
I have two classes `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`.
`FirstClass` has two pointers:

```
MyClass *character1;
MyClass *character2;
```

I assign to these pointers later in my code but now i have my `SecondClass` where i also have 2 pointers:

```
 MyClass *oldChar1;
 MyClass *oldChar2;
```

I want to set `oldChar` to the same as indicated by `character`. I made a function in `SecondClass` with friend clause in `FirstClass`.

```
void SecondClass::setChars()
{
    *oldChar1 = FirstClass::character1;
    *oldChar2 = FirstClass::character2;
}
```

Result:
`illegal reference to non-static member 'FirstClass::character1'`
I dont get it :/ Somebody can help me??

Comment: Which `FirstClass`'s pointers do you wish to use? Do you know the difference between a class and an object?

Comment: Ye I know the difference. I just want to `oldChar1` indicate to the same object made later as `character1`.

Comment: Apparently you _don't_ know the difference...

Comment: I think I understand that i cant assign to an object which doesnt exist yet. I just wonder how can I make it correct :P Any tips? Sorry for being lame :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches to do this.

**A friend function** shared in both classes ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404299/can-2-classes-share-a-friend-function)).

The friend function has access to the data members of the class MyFirstClass and MySecondClass, but the friend function still needs to be told which instances of those classes to use (see [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html)) e.g.

```
class MyClass {

};

class MySecondClass; //forward declaration for later

class MyFirstClass {

private:
  MyClass *character1;
  MyClass *character2;

public:
  //friend function
  friend void setChars(MyFirstClass& c1, MySecondClass& c2); //<---- friend function

};

class MySecondClass {

private:
  MyClass *oldChar1;
  MyClass *oldChar2;

public:
  //friend function
  friend void setChars(MyFirstClass& c1, MySecondClass& c2);

};

//define the friend function
void setChars(MyFirstClass& c1, MySecondClass& c2) {
  c2.oldChar1 = c1.character1;
  c2.oldChar2 = c1.character2;
}

int main() {

  MyFirstClass c1;
  MySecondClass c2;

  setChars(c1,c2);

}
```

**Friend Class**. 
Make MySecondClass a friend of MyFirstClass. MySecondClass will have method setChars which will take an instance of MyFirstClass as a parameter. e.g.

```
class MyClass {

};

class MySecondClass;

class MyFirstClass {

private:
  MyClass *character1;
  MyClass *character2;

public:   
  friend MySecondClass; //<----- friend class

};

class MySecondClass {

private:
  MyClass *oldChar1;
  MyClass *oldChar2;

public:

  void setCharsUsingFriendClass(MyFirstClass& c1) {
    oldChar1 = c1.character1;
    oldChar2 = c1.character2;
  }


};

int main() {

  MyFirstClass c1;
  MySecondClass c2;

  c2.setCharsUsingFriendClass(c1);

}
```

And finally using 2 getter methods. I think this approach is better because it allows the classes to hide their implementation details ([encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))).

```
class MyClass {

};

class MySecondClass;

class MyFirstClass {

private:
  MyClass *character1;
  MyClass *character2;

public:

  //define getters to access the private members
  MyClass* GetCharacter1() {return character1;}
  MyClass* GetCharacter2() {return character2;}
};

class MySecondClass {

private:
  MyClass *oldChar1;
  MyClass *oldChar2;

public:

  void setCharsUsingGetters(MyFirstClass& c1) {
    oldChar1 = c1.GetCharacter1();
    oldChar2 = c1.GetCharacter2();
  }
};

int main() {

  MyFirstClass c1;
  MySecondClass c2;

 c2.setCharsUsingGetters(c1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It opened my eyes to the things I did not quite correctly :)