# Access protected members outside class/struct scope?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, operator-overloading, protected

I have a bunch of templated structs (`Vec3<T>`, `Vec4<T>`, `Mat4<T>`, ...) and I'm doing lots of operator overloading. I've defined `Mat4<T> * Vec4<T>` as the usual matrix-vector multiplication. Now I wanted to define `Vec4<T> * Mat4<T>` as a row-by-row multiplication.

I also made the underlying data structure (I'm working with SIMD vectors) protected and the structs friends in order to access the protected `data` field.

The problem is that I would like to define `operator*(const Vec4<T>&, const Mat4<T>&)` in the `Mat4<T>` header file. Normally what I would do to define a commutative operator is:

```
template<typename T>
Vec3<T> operator*(const T & s, const Vec3<T> & v)
{
    return v * s;
}
```

But in this case I have to change the behaviour, and I cannot access the protected member of `Mat4<T>` and `Vec4<T>`.

- Is there a way to "make the function friend of the structs"?
- Alternatively, can I declare `operator*(const Mat4<T>&)` as a `Vec4<T>` member if `Mat4<T>` is an incomplete type (and later define it in the `Mat4<T>` header after the struct definition)?

NOTE: I would like to avoid a public getter like `const typename Mat4<T>::MT & getData() const;` that retrieves an immutable reference of `data`

## SOLUTION

The answer of @songyuanyao was almost right for me:

```
// In both Mat4 and Vec4
template<typename F>
friend Mat4<F> operator*(const Vec4<F> & v, const Mat4<F> & m);
```

Comment: Do you have `+` and `*` mixed up, in this question?

Comment: @NeilGatenby yeah, sorry. Fixed it

Comment: Declare the same `Mat4<T> operator*(const Vec4<T>&, const Mat4<T>&)` function as a friend to both structs? [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404299/can-2-classes-share-a-friend-function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to "make the function friend of the structs"?

Yes, you can declare a specialization of functioin template as `friend`. e.g.

```
// forward declaration
template<typename T>
class Vec4;
template<typename T>
class Mat4;

// declaration
template<typename T>
Vec4<T> operator*(const Vec4<T>&, const Mat4<T>&);

template<typename T>
class Vec4 {  
    // friend declaration  
    friend Vec4<T> operator* <T> (const Vec4<T>&, const Mat4<T>&);
    ...
};

template<typename T>
class Mat4 {    
    // friend declaration  
    friend Vec4<T> operator* <T> (const Vec4<T>&, const Mat4<T>&);
    ...
};

// definition  
template<typename T>
Vec4<T> operator*(const Vec4<T>&, const Mat4<T>&)
{
    ...
}
```